# How to include partials in another partials EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, ejs

I'm trying to include partial in another partial using EJS engine like this:

```
--First Partials
-----Second Partial
```

I get an error:

> Could not find the include file

Can anyone help me?
This is my code:
Part #1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<%- include parts/header %>

    <body>
        <%- include parts/section %>
    </body>

</html>
```

Part #2

```
<div class="de">
    <img src="img/de.svg" class="development" alt="">
    <%- include parts/postBlog %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the same direction, use that

```
<% include ./parts/header%>
<% include ./parts/section%>
```

If you want to back, use double dots.

```
<% include ../parts/header%>
<% include ../parts/section%>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Express 3.0:

```
<%- include myview.ejs %>
```

the path is relative from the caller who includes the file, not from the views directory set with :

```
app.set("views", "path/to/views");
```

[EJS includes](https://github.com/tj/ejs#includes)